# I don't get the complete table of an html with read_html

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I was trying to get the information from a table on a web page, using Panda, but it doesn't throw me all the information and other ways and I can't either.

```py
import pandas as pd
calls_df = pd.read_html("https://google.com/covid19-map/?hl=es-419", index_col=1,
                        attrs={"class":"SAGQRd"})
df = pd.DataFrame(calls_df)
print(calls_df)
```

I tried the code with other links and if they get the information from the tables, what is my error?

Comment: Please show what are you expect and what have you actually got?

Comment: Hello you are only selecting the classes with attributes `SAGQRd` with the parameter `attrs` restricting to `{"class":"SAGQRd"}`. You can inspect the html source code of the page to see what classes you want and adjust accordingly. Hope it helps

Comment: Or you can remove the parameters you put to pandas `read_html`, you get a list of two DataFrames and then you can extract the info you want from them.

Answer (score 0):

pandas could probably not be the best way to get html data, try exploring the BeautifulSoup Module from  : https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

to load html into df, try:

```
`import pandas as pd
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
 table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'subs noBorders evenRows'})
 table_rows = table.find_all('tr')`

 `res = []
 for tr in table_rows:
      td = tr.find_all('td')
      row = [tr.text.strip() for tr in td if tr.text.strip()]
      if row:
          res.append(row)

 df = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["Year", "Mintage", "Quality", "Price"])
 print(df)`
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't get all the information from a table. Now, I can see the table only 15 rows and there are more rows. 
I tested your code and still get 15 rows.

Comment: Ill have to look at the html to figure this out further... there might be some format/type changes somewhere. Although BeautfulSoup is a powerful library very apt for your requirements..please go through the docs and see if that helps.. keep in mind that it uses parses by adjusting your data into trees so you can actually parse through each node and see exactly where your data goes missing

Answer (score -1):

[jupyter_code_check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iFhZ.png)

Hey,

i just checked your code via jupyter and it worked for me.
Are you also working with jupyter? It could be that the cache is a bit full :D
Restart your IDE, or Computer

my setup:

Python 3.7.4

Name: pandas
Version: 0.25.1

Name: jupyter
Version: 1.0.0